# How to create a function that activates within a time limit unless user gives input in python

Tags: python, tkinter, time, python-multithreading

I am trying to create a `button` in `tkinter` that once pressed, program waits for a specific time (here 1 second) and if the user doesn't press that `button` again, the function `fun()` is executed.
How can I get it to work?
To note, the `button` by default executes `fun()`, and also executes `fun2()` first time only.

```
import time
import threading
from tkinter import *

def fun():
    global label
    restart = time.perf_counter()
    label.pack()

def fun2(event, start):
    global restart
    restart = start
    but.unbind("<Button-1>", bind_no)
    t1 = threading.Thread(target = fun3)
    t1.start()

def fun3():
    global restart
    while True:
        while time.perf_counter()-restart<1:
            pass
        label.pack()


root = Tk()

label = Label(root, text="fun")

but = Button(root, text= "Click", command= fun)
bind_no = but.bind("<Button-1>", lambda eff: fun2(eff, time.perf_counter()))
but.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need `threading` or `time`; the mechanism to achieve the delayed/cancel behavior you describe can be implemented using `tk.after`

Maybe like this:

1- the button calls `delay_action_fun`
2- `delay_action_fun` triggers a callback that will call `fun` in one second.
3- if the button is not pressed again, `fun` is executed.
3.1 - if the button is pressed again before the callback is executed, the callback to `fun` is cancelled.

rinse & repeat.

```
import tkinter as tk

def fun():
    global call_back
    print('executing fun')
    call_back = None

def delay_action_fun():
    """calls fun to xeq in 1 second, but cancels the callback if
    triggered again within that time period
    """
    global call_back
    print('pressed')
    if call_back is None:
        call_back = root.after(1000, fun)
    else:
        print('cancelling cb')
        root.after_cancel(call_back)
        call_back = None

root = tk.Tk()

call_back = None
tk.Button(root, text= "xeq fun", command=delay_action_fun).pack()

root.mainloop()
```